# How to get items with scrapy when they are not showing in the HTML source

Tags: scrapy

I am using scrapy to get products of https://arcteryx.com/de/de/c/mens/new-arrivals?intcmp=home_t1_c_mens_new-arrivals. However when i look at page source no products appear (hidden by javascript??). Thus, naturally cannot get any of them on scrapy shell with `response.css('div[class^="LazyProductTile__Wrap"]')`

How do I bypass it and get the list of products and their details? Does it have to do with lazy loading?

Comment: This was answered before. In short, Scrapy can't parse dynamically loaded content. Search for solutions on SO, maybe you'll find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Scrapy Spash, that allowed getting the content.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).